# Trying to install program via powershell, getting strange error

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to install a 3rd party program via powershell.

I'm using the command:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Users\User.Name\Desktop\Setup.exe" -ArgumentList /s,/v,/qn -passthru
```

But when I run that command it returns the following error: ["Invalid Command Line"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zxWL.png)

Comment: Do you get the error without the argument list?

Comment: are you sure, that `/s`, `/v` and `/qn` are valid command line arguments for your third party program?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter -ArgumentList is a String, you haven't pass a string
Something like this "/s,/v,/qn" could be OK.

Comment: I appreciate your help Oliver, but unfortunately even with the addition of the quotes I'm still getting the same error. Do you know of any further arguments I could use to maybe see a more verbose error? I assumed with the /v that was the best I would get, but if I could see a better error perhaps I could narrow down my issue.